# Python / Google Drive API - What is the difference between orderBy 'name' and orderBy 'name_natural'?

Tags: python, list, google-drive-api

According to Google API doc:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

orderBy:
A comma-separated list of sort keys. Valid keys are 'createdTime', 'folder', 'modifiedByMeTime', 'modifiedTime', 'name', 'name_natural', 'quotaBytesUsed', 'recency', 'sharedWithMeTime', 'starred', and 'viewedByMeTime'.

Please, what is the difference between 'name' and 'name_natural'?

Thanks for your help,
Bests,

Comment: Do you see any differences in the responses?

Comment: I proposed an answer for explaining the difference between `name_natural` and `name`. Could you please confirm it? But I'm not sure whether that is the direction you expect. So if my answer was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Hello, thanks @Tanaike it sheds some light on this topic. Actually, with the names I am managing, number of digits are the same in the filename, so I would not have been able to see this difference. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `name_natural` might mean the natural sort. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4836710/7108653) For example, it supposes that the following files are put in a folder.

[image]

I thought that you might be able to understand about the difference between `name_natural` and `name` from the results using these sample files with `name_natural` and `name`.

#### 1. `name_natural` order:

When the file list is retrieved with the following command,

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?orderBy=name_natural&q=%27%23%23%23%27%20in%20parents&fields=files(name)' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

- In this case, `orderBy`, `q` and `fields` are `name_natural`, `'{folderId}' in parents` and `files(name)`, respectively.

The following result is retrieved.

```
{"files":[
    {"name":"ss1"},
    {"name":"ss01"},
    {"name":"ss02"},
    {"name":"ss03"},
    {"name":"ss04"},
    {"name":"ss05"},
    {"name":"ss06"},
    {"name":"ss07"},
    {"name":"ss08"},
    {"name":"ss09"},
    {"name":"ss10"},
    {"name":"ss11"},
    {"name":"ss12"},
    {"name":"ss100"},
    {"name":"ss1000"}
]}
```

- The file of `ss1` is the top of the list.
- The files of `ss100` and `ss1000` are the end of the list.
- From this result and above sample image, it seems that the default sort by name of the interface on Google Drive is `name_natural`.

#### 2. `name` order:

When the file list is retrieved with the following command,

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?orderBy=name&q=%27%23%23%23%27%20in%20parents&fields=files(name)' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

- In this case, `orderBy`, `q` and `fields` are `name`, `'{folderId}' in parents` and `files(name)`, respectively.

The following result is retrieved.

```
{"files":[
    {"name":"ss01"},
    {"name":"ss02"},
    {"name":"ss03"},
    {"name":"ss04"},
    {"name":"ss05"},
    {"name":"ss06"},
    {"name":"ss07"},
    {"name":"ss08"},
    {"name":"ss09"},
    {"name":"ss1"},
    {"name":"ss10"},
    {"name":"ss100"},
    {"name":"ss1000"},
    {"name":"ss11"},
    {"name":"ss12"}
]}
```

- The file of `ss1` is not the top of the list.
- The files of `ss100` and `ss1000` are not the end of the list.

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Is there a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4836710/7108653)